# Remote Access to Android Device Out of State

Tags: android, remote-access

I travel a lot and sometimes need to access an Android device that I left at home. I'm looking for a Teamviewer-like solution that can remotely access my device from my PC, and allows me to do everything, including opening apps.

I've tried various pieces of software on the Play Store, but haven't yet been able to find one that meets the above specifications. For example, TeamViewer allows me to see my phone's screen, but I can't open apps (instead, it just points at the apps on the Android's screen with a blue pointer). Other solutions allow me transfer files, but I cannot open apps.

Is there anything out there that does what I'm looking for?

Many thanks for all your help and thoughts!

Comment: I've never approached that myself, so I cannot say which tool solves the issue. But you might wish to take a look at my matching lists, e.g. [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement) and [Control your Droid from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid). From the last one, VNC solutions might be the closest to what you describe.